# How to disable 'X-Frame-Options' response header in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, x-frame-options

I have CKeditor on my JSP and whenever I upload something, the following error pops out:

```
 Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/upload-image?CKEditor=text&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=ru' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

I have tried removing Spring Security and everything works like a charm.

- How can I disable this in Spring Security XML file?
- What should I write between `<http>` tags?

Comment: None of the answers below yet address whether it's possible to apply SAMEORIGIN or ALLOW at the controller method level - anyone know?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

By default `X-Frame-Options` is set to denied, to prevent [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) attacks. To override this, you can add the following into your spring security config

```
<http>    
    <headers>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    </headers>
</http>
```

Here are available options for policy

- **DENY** - is a default value. With this the page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.
- **SAMEORIGIN** - I assume this is what you are looking for, so that the page will be (and can be) displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself
- **ALLOW-FROM** - Allows you to specify an origin, where the page can be displayed in a frame.

For more information take a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-frame-options).

And [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html) to check how you can configure the headers using either XML or Java configs.

Note, that you might need also to specify appropriate `strategy`, based on needs.

Comment: What is the namespace for this `http` and `headers` tags?

Comment: Is it possible to apply this as the controller method level?

Comment: If you need to configure it within WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's configure method, write the following code: `http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();`

Comment: @vtor I use spring 3.1 and this is not supported, any workaround you might suggest?

Comment: @Spring https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-frame-options it is supported. Could you please share what you have tried and didn't work?

Comment: When I have applied xrfameoptions in spring security XML, it is set on all response headers except for login page. I wonder what went wrong?!

Answer (score 137):

If you're using Java configs instead of XML configs, put this in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity http)` method:

```
http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

Comment: Using disable() is an option but if it's on the same server, use `http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();`

Comment: what if i mix :-)

Comment: .headers(headers -> headers
      .frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::disable))

Answer (score 73):

Most likely you don't want to deactivate this Header completely, but use `SAMEORIGIN`. If you are using the Java Configs (`Spring Boot`) and would like to allow the X-Frame-Options: `SAMEORIGIN`, then you would need to use the following.

---

For older Spring Security versions:

```
http
   .headers()
       .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
```

---

For newer versions like [Spring Security 4.0.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-frame-options):

```
http
   .headers()
      .frameOptions()
         .sameOrigin();
```

Comment: How to configure this in Spring 3.2.12?

Comment: Migrating from 3.X to 4.X and ran into this as it was just appending based on the first example. thx.

Comment: Thanks. http.headers().frameOptions().sameorigin(); worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

If using XML configuration you can use

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"> 
<security:http>
    <security:headers>
         <security:frame-options disabled="true"></security:frame-options>
    </security:headers>
</security:http>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Spring Security's Java configuration, all of the default security headers are added by default. They can be disabled using the Java configuration below:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .headers().disable()
      ...;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Spring Boot, the simplest way to disable the Spring Security default headers is to use `security.headers.*` properties. In particular, if you want to disable the `X-Frame-Options` default header, just add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
security.headers.frame=false
```

There is also `security.headers.cache`, `security.headers.content-type`, `security.headers.hsts` and `security.headers.xss` properties that you can use. For more information, take a look at [`SecurityProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties.java#L171).

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.x this method is deprecated. "The security auto-configuration is no longer customizable. Provide your own WebSecurityConfigurer bean instead."

Answer (score 2):

You should configure multiple HttpSecurity instances.

Here is my code where only ***/public/***** requests are without ***X-Frame-Options*** header.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

/**
 * Public part - Embeddable Web Plugin
 */

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class EmbeddableWebPluginSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Disable X-Frame-Option Header
        http.antMatcher("/public/**").headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
}

/**
 * Private part - Web App Paths
 */

@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public static class SSOWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**", "/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/error**", "/static/**", "/robots", "/robot", "/robot.txt", "/robots.txt")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/bye");
    }

    /**
     * Public API endpoints
     */

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/**");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you prevent overriding existing rules when calling `antMatcher(String)`?

Answer (score 0):

`.csrf().disable()` its to dangerous.

test:

```
.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
```

Answer (score 0):

with lambda_dsl (spring security 6.2 and prepare for 7.x)

```
http.headers(header.frameOptions(frameOptions -> Customizer.withDefaults());)

http.headers(header->{header.frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin);})

http.headers(header->{header.frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::disable);})
```

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your answer and provide some explanation as to how these lambdas solve the issue described in the posted question?