# Spring default x-frame-options

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-headers, x-frame-options

I've recently upgraded from Spring 3.2.2 to version 4.2.1.

As a result, http response headers defaults were changed, and now it contains these parameters:

> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>
> X-Frame-Options: DENY
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

How can I change the **default** security headers of spring?

Comment: Are you using spring-security ? Which version did you change from to ?  AFAIK these are not added by spring-core/spring-web* only spring-security.  Do you configure it in code or XML ?

Comment: X-Frame-Options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647136/how-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-in-spring-security ... For spring-security 4.0.3.RELEASE try the documentation around http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-frame-options and search the page for each header.