# Refused to display ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. at loading jsp by jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have working web project.

I have created view controller for jsp page

When i loading jsp page into another jsp by jquery. 
It is passiing

```
Refused to display ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

I have imported like this...

```
            $(".tab-content").append(
                "<div class='tab-pane' id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>"
                +"<iframe src='leads-creation' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>"
                + "</div>"
            );
```

I have created view controller already

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Frame-Options` is response's header to tell the browser if run iframes or not from security issue. You can change the value of this header to `ALLOW-FROM` for example.

This question explain more: [How to disable 'X-Frame-Options' response header in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647136/how-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-in-spring-security)