# How to give request matcher in Spring Security for x frame options?

Tags: spring-security

I have enabled Spring Security headers.

My code is like this:

```xml
<security:headers disabled="false">
       <security:content-security-policy policy-directives="script-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
       <security:cache-control disabled="true"/>
</security:headers>
```

By default `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` is `DENY`.
But some requests I should enable `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` as `SAMEORIGIN`. How to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647136/how-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-in-spring-security/66580815#66580815

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/header/writers/DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter.html), see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-delegatingrequestmatcherheaderwriter):

> **20.2.3 DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter**
>
> At times you may want to only write a header for certain requests. For example, perhaps you want to only protect your log in page from being framed. You could use the `DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter` to do so. When using the XML namespace configuration, this can be done with the following:
>
> ```xml
> <http>
>   <!-- ... -->
>
>   <headers>
>       <frame-options disabled="true"/>
>       <header ref="headerWriter"/>
>   </headers>
> </http>
>
> <beans:bean id="headerWriter"
> class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter">
>   <beans:constructor-arg>
>       <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher"
>         c:pattern="/login"/>
>   </beans:constructor-arg>
>   <beans:constructor-arg>
>       <beans:bean
>         class="org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.frameoptions.XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter"/>
>   </beans:constructor-arg>
> </beans:bean>
> ```

To use `DENY`and `SAMEORIGIN` for different URLs you have to add two `header` elements with two different `DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter`.