# How to add HTTP “Feature-Policy” header in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, content-security-policy

I need to add  HTTP “Feature-Policy” response header but I did not find any way implement this in spring in header like -

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        // ...
        .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com; object-src https://trustedplugins.example.com; report-uri /csp-report-endpoint/");
    }
```

I can see the draft specification [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1k0Ua-ZWlM_PsFCFdLMa8kaVTo32PeNZ4G7FFHqpFx4E/edit#) but not much about use it in Spring. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: this might be useful for your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360215/how-to-create-a-spring-interceptor-for-spring-restful-web-services

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111346/how-to-give-request-matcher-in-spring-security-for-x-frame-options

Answer (score 2):

To create custom header you should use `addHeaderWriter` and add `StaticHeadersWriter`

example:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        // ...
        .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com; object-src https://trustedplugins.example.com; report-uri /csp-report-endpoint/")
            .and()
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Feature-Policy", "vibrate 'none'; usermedia 'none'"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security has been introduced a support for `Feature-Policy` in 5.1 so this can be configured as other headers:

```java
http
    .headers()
        .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'");
```

For the version 5.2+ the code is a little bit different:

```java
http
    .headers(headers ->
        headers.featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'")
    );
```

See documentation for details:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.x/reference/html/default-security-headers-2.html#webflux-headers-feature-configure
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#servlet-headers-feature

---

**UPDATE:** @granty has pointed out that the `Feature-Policy` header has been renamed to `Permissions-Policy`. The upcoming Spring Security 5.5.0-M2 will support it. Here is how it will look like:

```java
http
    .headers(headers ->
        headers.permissionsPolicy(permissions ->
            permissions.policy("geolocation=(self)")
        )
    );
```

See also the related pull request: [#9265](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/9265)

Comment: A little bit late. A year ago they make a mess and [renamed the Feature Policy](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/issues/359) and now it's a [Permissions Policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/permissions-policy/). Therefore you still have to use `addHeaderWriter()` / `StaticHeadersWriter()` to publish Permissions-Policy header.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I've addressed this error:

```
http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
    .and()
        .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy(...)
    .and()
        .referrerPolicy(...)
    .and()
        .permissionsPolicy().policy("camera=*, fullscreen=(self), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), midi=(), payment=(), sync-xhr=()")
   ...;
```