# Change x-frame-options header for a single controller in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, x-frame-options

Imagine you have a spring boot application and you only want to create one page which can be embedded as iFrame. All other pages should still have the default `x-frame-options: deny` header.

- I couldn't find a corresponding annotation (I expected something like the `@CrossOrigin` annotation, but generic for headers)
- I tried to change the headers through the `httpServletResponse` but it seems that the security headers get overwritten afterwards
- I tried to use `http.antmatcher("/controller").frameOptions().disable()` but this breaks the rest of my authentication - and I miss a `.allow(domain)` method

I know that I could create some filter code but I hope that there is a simpler solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111346/how-to-give-request-matcher-in-spring-security-for-x-frame-options

Comment: thanx. I will give it a try but hoped for a solution without having to code...

Answer (score 0):

To allow iframe options only for a specific controller and not allow it for all the website this is my approach:

```
 @RequestMapping("/someiframepath")
    public String iframe(HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
        response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "");
        .... DO SOMETHING ....
        return "your view";
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx! I think this is indeed the solution I was looking for!

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Spring security gets priority, so my header is ignored.  Any suggestions?  Using spring boot 1.5.18

Answer (score -1):

Setting these headers to the response worked for me.

```
response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", " frame-ancestors 'self'");
```

**X-Frame-Options** has been superseded by **Content-Security-Policy (frame-ancestors)** but it's not being supported by some browsers so it's better to set both for now.
Reference: https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/web_security#x-frame-options