# Why the support for ContentSecurityPolicy support on the HttpSecurity?

Tags: spring-security

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) we can set the CSP protection via HTML like so.

```html
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self https://*;" />
```

in the main HTML page.

Spring security DSL supports the setting of Content-Security-Policy header like so:

```
httpSecurity.headers((HeadersConfigurer<HttpSecurity> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer) -> {
            httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer.contentSecurityPolicy(
                    (HeadersConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ContentSecurityPolicyConfig contentSecurityPolicyConfig) -> {
                contentSecurityPolicyConfig.policyDirectives("default-src 'self' https://*");
            });
        });
```

This will send the response header on **all the responses** handled by that security filter chain. But why should the `Content-Security-Policy` policy response header be sent back on all responses. Shouldn't it be only sent on the main page response for resource like `index.html`?

And if it is being sent on all responses, why not just implement a global filter like so:

```
    @Component
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public static class CSPFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self' https://*");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Why is the support on security filter chain?

Comment: *Shouldn't it be only sent on the main page response for resource like index.html?* How should Spring Security know your starting URLs? Why do you think, there is only one starting URL.

Comment: *And if it is being sent on all responses, why not just implement a global filter like so:`* Sure you could implement it by yourself. Spring Securitty is a framework and supports it, so you don't need to implement it by yourself, you can configure it.

Comment: @dur Well, it could be based on content type text/html etc or the programmer could specify all starting pages etc. I asked the question because sending the header on responses that do not need it seems wasteful. Also, I thought there may be some other reason I am not thinking of as to why it is supported at HttpSecurity level.

Comment: I filed an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14092

Which points to: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/headers.html#headers-delegatingrequestmatcherheaderwriter

Comment: Reading your issue, I remember, that I answered the question already some years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111346/how-to-give-request-matcher-in-spring-security-for-x-frame-options Sorry, I forgot it.