# Spring boot - Not rendering the landing(index.html) page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**I've tried the answers related to the question in stackoverflow**. It did not work out.

Here is my project structure :

[image]

Controller: To render the `index.html`

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homepage(){
        System.out.println("Inside controller..");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to hit the `URL`, it prints `Inside controller..` but not rendering the `index` page. Tried using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` as well.

In browser, it displays some error like **Whitelabel Error Page**

Am I missing something out here?

Comment: What did you get in browser

Comment: @user6690200 ,Whitelabel Error Page,no explicit mapping

Comment: Which technologies you are using at front end like angular ,thymeleaf ?

Comment: @KishorVelayutham open your `target` folder, check if there is `index.html` or not.

Comment: @RameshFadatare,I'm using Angular at front end

Comment: @user6690200, target folder ? index.html is in resources/templates folder

Comment: It should be compiled to `target` folder by your IDE or maven at compile stage. At runtime, your application will seek `index.html` from `target` folder. So, it there it is, it means something wrong with your mapping configuration. If not, it means something wrong with your classpath.

Comment: could you try if change the return statement to "forward:index.html" and try

Comment: @RSingh, I will try and let you know.

Comment: Whomever, Let me know the reason for downvote? Don't downvote just like that. Tell the reason so that i can change. Be professional.

Comment: @RSingh, I tried using forward as well as redirect. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors in the browser console. 'X-Frame-Options' may be set to 'DENY' that may block html page to load in the browser.

This [How to disable 'X-Frame-Options' response header in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647136/how-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-in-spring-security) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your project structure. Application, and other packages like model, controller etc. should be under the same package or on the same level. Also make sure there are no extra configuration on application.yml/properties file regarding "spring.thymeleaf.prefix".

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJt6Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

try using full name with extension like index.html

Answer (score -3):

I think you shouldn't return String. Try instead something like `ModelAndView`.

Comment: Yes, you can do that but it's not necessary so this is not the problem. Here's an example : https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/