# spring boot security doesn't let me access h2-console

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, h2

I'm trying to implement JWT in Spring Boot. For some debugging purposes, I need an H2 console.

So in my **WebSecurityConfiguration**, I wrote :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2").permitAll();
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/check/username").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

In my application properties, I have this configuration :

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

When I hit ":8080/h2", it gives me **403**.

So the question remains, how can I properly configure Spring Boot Web Security.

After including `/h2/**`, I get this UI :

[image: spring boot blocking h2 console]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try "h2" pattern as:

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll();
```

And this too :

```
httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

more can found here : [How to disable 'X-Frame-Options' response header in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28647136/10305444)

Comment: please check the question again

Comment: h2 cosole is loading fine, I tried in Chrome (Version 84.0.4147.89 ) and MS Edge browsers , please check once

Comment: I don't know how you made it worked, but I need this : `httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();`, i have edited the answer, accept it, then I will accept this as an answer